# Multiple Queues in C

Tags: c, queue

I have a basic queue design, but I want to have multiple queues. The way it looks right now is that I would need another queue.h file and replace head and tail with different names, but I am sure there is a better way?

**queue.h *Edited**

```
#include<stdlib.h>  // malloc

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Queue {
  struct Node *head, *tail;
};

struct Queue *QueueInit() {
    //allocate and initialize a queue
    struct Queue *thisQueue = malloc(sizeof *thisQueue);
    thisQueue->head = NULL;
    thisQueue->tail = NULL;
    return thisQueue;
}


void push(struct Queue *myQueue, int x) {
    struct Node *temp; 
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;  
    if(myQueue->head == NULL && myQueue->tail == NULL) { //empty
        myQueue->head = myQueue->tail = temp;
        return;
    }
    myQueue->tail->next = temp;
    myQueue->tail = temp;
}

void pop(struct Queue *myQueue) {
    struct Node* temp = myQueue->head;
    if(myQueue->head == NULL) return;   //empty
    if(myQueue->head == myQueue->tail) {
        myQueue->head = myQueue->tail = NULL;
    }
    else {
        myQueue->head = myQueue->head->next;
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

How can I create multiple queues like this?

**main.c**

```
int main() {
    struct Node iceCreamLine;
    struct Node bathroomLine;

    iceCreamLine.push(13);
    bathroomLine.push(2);


    //It looks like I will have to use this syntax then instead?
    struct Queue *droneQueue;    //(THIS IS LINE 5)
    push(&droneQueue,1666);
    push(&droneQueue,100);

    printf("--> %d",&droneQueue->head->data);
    printf("--> %d",&droneQueue->head->next->data);

}
```

The first printf works, but the second one gives me a segmentation dump. Also here are the warnings

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘push’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from queue.c:2:0:
queue.h:21:6: note: expected ‘struct Queue *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Queue **’
main.c:7:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘push’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from queue.c:2:0:
queue.h:21:6: note: expected ‘struct Queue *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Queue **’
main.c:9:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
main.c:10:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]

Comment: For the push notation `iceCreamLine.push(13);` to work, you'd need an element `void (*push)(int);` in the `struct Node` structure, and you'd have to ensure that each `struct Node` is initialized properly so that the `push` element points to the correct function.

Comment: Creating new versions of the file with different names for `head` and `tail`, etc, would be a disaster.  +1 for suspecting as much and bothering to ask before implementing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Queue {
  struct Node *head, *tail;
};
```

Add a `QueueInit` function to allocate and initialize a queue, returning a pointer to a `struct Queue`. Pass a pointer to `struct Queue` to `push` and `pop`, and get rid of your global `head` and `tail`.

Comment: I edited my code above, but I am not from a C background. What would the head and tail get init to? And how will push and pop know what head and tail is?     Thanks

Comment: Based on your other code, you would init `head` and `tail` to `NULL`. You would add a `struct Queue *` to the parameter list for push and pop - `void push(struct Queue *myQueue, int x)` and `void pop(struct Queue *myQueue)`. Within `push` and `pop`, you would refer to `myQueue->head` and `myQueue->tail`. Also, your `QueueInit` should have a `return thisQueue;`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I almost have it working. I did want the syntax like iceCreamLine.push(13); instead of push(&iceCreamLine,13), but that will do. I edited the code to what you all said, but get warnings and a segmentation dump on my second printf.    I've come to hate pointers!

Comment: As you are declaring `droneQueue` as a pointer, you shouldn't be sending it to `push` with a `&`. `&droneQueue` means a pointer to `droneQueue`, so as you have coded it, a pointer to a pointer. Getting rid of all of your `&`s should help. Also, don't forget to initialize `droneQueue` by assigning it the return value of `QueueInit`.